# KeyStore error: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, keystore

I'm trying to load a PKCS12KeyStore in Java, but I have a problem, if I run the application inside the IDE (I'm using Netbeans), it works fine, but if I run outside in another pc, throws the error:

> `failed to decrypt safe contents entry: java.lang.ArithmeticException:
>   / by zero, and i found the error is in this line (ks.load(certPKCS12,
>   password.toCharArray());)`

where `ks` is `KeyStore` type. I think the problem could be with some dependency, but I tried to manually copy all .jar files I depends on but the results is always the same. 
Now I made another test in PC with JVM8 and it works, but in others doesn't. I don't really no idea what about this. I appreciate some help